# How can I compute $div(rotF(0,0,0))$ of $F = (2y,3x,z)$?

Tags: calculus

**How** can I compute $$div(rotF(0,0,0)), F = (2y,3x,z)$$

**My insights:**

First, I computed $rotF$ with $3\times3$ determinant, and got **(Edited:)**$(0,0,1)$.

I didn't use the fact that the given point is $(0,0,0)$ in the determinant. and I don't know how to use it. Moreover, no idea how to use $div$ too.

**Is there a formula?** I think there is with a gradient, etc.

Comment: $\text{rot }F$ should itself be a vector, not a scalar. (Which it had better be, since one takes the divergence of a _vector_ field.)

Comment: @Semiclassical Right. So it would be $(0,0,1)$

Comment: Right, and the divergence of that is easy to compute. Note that, in this case, the evaluation at the origin doesn't matter. But there are definitely cases where it would, and in those cases you would need to do rot and div _before_ plugging in (0,0,0).

Comment: Well, Zubzub gave me a reference where it would be always zero. for any vector. @Semiclassical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The divergence of the curl is always $0$.
See [this](http://www.oberlin.edu/physics/dstyer/Electrodynamics/DivCurl.pdf), [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities)
or [that](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/CurlDivergence.aspx)

Using the definition of the divergence and the curl, it is not too difficult to prove it for yourself, just a bit tedious because curl is cumbersome to develop... !
(Also I should point out that if you want to prove this fact by developing *curl* and then applying *div* you should have [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives) in mind)

Comment: Wow. This is a fact I was not aware of. Thank you!